Stubbing class after intercept load calls happens
I want when a GET request of my desired file finishes with success to stub that class .
Currently what happens is I hit the index.html page all the files get loaded including the MyCustomClass.js via "GET", "http://127.0.0.1:9002/services/managers/MyCustomClass.js" and after the load of all files , the backend continues with invoking MyCustomClass.myMethod() , now I want once the GET request finishes for MyCustomClass.js to stub the return value of MyCustomClass.myMethod() to be "123" and then to continue with all other loads the app does.
Current order of events is:

All the files get loaded with GET requests and the intercept of @loadMyCustomClass is registered

the backend calls MyCustomClass.myMethod() with the original value

cy.wait("@loadMyCustomClass", { timeout: 7200000 }).then(() => which stubs


I want to swap 2 and 3.
  open(): MainPage {
    clock.execAsOn(() => {
      cy.intercept("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:9002/services/managers/MyCustomClass.js").as(
        "loadMyCustomClass"
      );

      cy.visit("index.html");

      // Wait for the network request that loads MyCustomClass
      cy.wait("@loadMyCustomClass", { timeout: 7200000 }).then(() => {
        // Wait until MyCustomClass is attached to the window object
        // Stub the static method once MyCustomClass is available
        cy.window().then((win) => {
          cy.stub(win.MyCustomClass, "myMethod").returns("123");
          console.log("MyCustomClass.myMethod is stubbed");
        });
      });

class :
// MyCustomClass.ts
class MyCustomClass {
  // Define a static method
  public static myMethod(): string {
    return "MyCustomClass myMethod value";
  }

  // Define an instance method
  public anotherMethod(): string {
    return "MyCustomClass anotherMethod value";
  }
}

console.log("Class loaded");
console.log(window.MyCustomClass);
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  (window as any).MyCustomClass = MyCustomClass; // Attach to window object
}
console.log(window.MyCustomClass);
export default MyCustomClass;



It seems to work ok, what error are you getting?

it runs , but not the correct way , as I mentioned during the load of the page "index.html" i want to stub the class , but it seems it doesn't want to get stubbed because the order of execution of events is wrong

Stubbing should not be done with cy.intercept() and/or wait function since they occur asynchronously to the loading sequence.
Instead you will use the hooks provided
onBeforeLoad Provide an onBeforeLoad callback function
onLoad Provide an onLoad callback function
onLoad look better, it will wait for the index load then provide stub before testing.
cy.visit('index.html', {
  onLoad: (contentWindow) => {
    cy.stub(contentWindow.MyCustomClass, "myMethod").returns("123")
  },
})


that will work only if the object is used later on in the test where the page is already loaded and set up, the problem is I want the stub to be applied during the page setup or more precisely after the class is loaded during page setup

I had a feeling you would have difficulty with this. There is only onBeforeLoad or onLoad, but no onSometimeDuringLoad for obvious reasons. E2e testing is black-box, it doesn't know what's going on inside the app. You may be able to hack some more code into the app code to make it work, i.e check the custom class for an existing stub.
